# PHP Different Arrays in Foreach-loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, slideshow

I want to have a Slideshow for each item.

It is only working with the first one, for the others it doesn't work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

My code:

```
<?php
            // check $items variable exists and is not empty
            if(isset($items) && !empty($items)) :
                // init item count
                $count = 1;
            ?>
            <div class="shelf">

                <?php foreach($items as $key=>$item): ?>
                    <?php
                    // calculate if this item is the last on the shelf
                    // if item number can be divided by 5 with no remainders
                    $last_item = ( (($count) % 5 == 0)? 'item-last' : '' );
                    ?>

                    <div class="item <?php echo $last_item; ?>">
                        <a href="/items/view/<?php echo $item['Item']['slug']; ?>">
                        <p><?php echo $item['Item']['name'] ?></p>




                    <div id="CustomSlideshow">  


<?php
if ($item['Item']['vidsite'] = 'Pornhub') {

for($i=1;$i<=16;$i++) {
   $array[] = str_replace('.jpg',sprintf("%01d",$i).'.jpg',$item['Item']['vidimgdir']);
} ?>
<img src="<?php echo($array[0]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[1]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[2]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[3]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[4]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[5]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[6]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[7]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[8]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[9]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[10]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[11]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[12]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[13]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[14]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[15]); ?>"/>
<?php
 $array=array();
 } ?>


</div>                      

                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                    // if this is the last item, close the shelf div and create a new one
                    if(!empty($last_item)) {
                        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="shelf">';
                    }
                    ?>
                <?php $count++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($item['Item']['vidsite'] = 'Pornhub') {
```

My guess is you have forgotten one equality sign, so your code keeps assigning the same value to `$item['Item']['vidsite']`.
One equality sign (`=`) assigns the value to the item, two (`==`) compare the operand, thus you should replace `=` with `==`.
Perhaps you already knew this and have just mistyped it. Don't worry, I also used to make this mistake. ;)

---

And by the way - if I were you, I'd replace the following code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=16;$i++) {
   $array[] = str_replace('.jpg',sprintf("%01d",$i).'.jpg',$item['Item']['vidimgdir']);
} ?>
<img src="<?php echo($array[0]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[1]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[2]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[3]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[4]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[5]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[6]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[7]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[8]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[9]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[10]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[11]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[12]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[13]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[14]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[15]); ?>"/>
```

with this one:

```
for($i=0;$i<=15;$i++) {
   $array[] = str_replace('.jpg',sprintf("%01d",$i).'.jpg',$item['Item']['vidimgdir']);
   echo '<img src="'.$array[$i].'"/>';
} ?>
```

Much shorter.